# 404 error with Node.js app deployed to Vercel using fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, fetch

I am creating a website using Node.js to fetch image data from the image URL and showing the result on the page. I plan to turn it into a web scraping tool on the web to scrape image data from webpages instead of just image URLs.

When I open the console on Microsoft Edge after inputting in the image URL then pressing the button the error "/api/fetch-image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.alfred.edu%2Fzoom%2F_images%2Ffall-drone-shot-thumbnail.jpg:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" comes up. It worked perfectly fine using a localhost proxy server of 3000 but doesn't work on Vercel. I also edited it so that the code doesn't include the proxy 3000 for Vercel.

The image URL I am using is: https://my.alfred.edu/zoom/_images/fall-drone-shot-thumbnail.jpg

The vercel URL to my app is: https://billionaire-shopping-game-web.vercel.app/

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Image Fetcher</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Image Fetcher</h1>
  <form id="image-form">
    <label for="url">Enter the image URL:</label>
    <input type="text" id="url" name="url">
    <button type="submit">Fetch Image</button>
  </form>
  <div id="image-container"></div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "billionaire-shopping-game-web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

main.js

```
document.getElementById('image-form').addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const urlInput = document.getElementById('url');
  const imageUrl = urlInput.value;
  
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/fetch-image?url=${encodeURIComponent(imageUrl)}`);
    
    if (response.ok) {
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const imageSrc = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const imageContainer = document.getElementById('image-container');
      imageContainer.innerHTML = `<img src="${imageSrc}" alt="Fetched Image">`;
    } else {
      console.error(response.status);
      alert('Error fetching image');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    alert('Error fetching image');
  }
});
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();

app.get('/api/fetch-image', async (req, res) => {
  const imageUrl = req.query.url;
  
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(imageUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
    const imageData = Buffer.from(response.data, 'base64');
    res.contentType('image/jpeg');
    res.send(imageData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Error fetching image');
  }
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: It seems like it has something to do with your vercel conf. Try visiting [it](https://billionaire-shopping-game-web.vercel.app/api/fetch-image)

Comment: Do you mean the vercel configuration file? I visited the link you gave me. The vercel config wasn't included.